# imap_fetchbody doesn't read mail with html template

Tags: php, html, email, imap

imap_fetchbody doesn't read mails with html template for **PARTICULAR** gmail id.
i have tried all the following imap part numbers 
0 - Message header , 
1 - MULTIPART/ALTERNATIVE , 
1.1 - TEXT/PLAIN , 
1.2 - TEXT/HTML , 
2 - file.ext.

`imap_fetchbody($connection,$email_number,$partNum,FT_UID);`

Is there any settings in gmail other than IMAP Access ?

and also want to know that " Is FT_UID neccessary in the code ? "

Comment: 1.1 doesn't always mean text and 1.2 doesn't always mean HTML.  You need to evaluate the body structure to be sure.